# Direction routing in transit mode using Windows Phone 8.1 maps API

Tags: dictionary, windows-phone-8.1, here-api

Is there a way to return routing in transit mode (eg. using public transport) using WP 8.1 native maps service API?

Some side questions:

1. WP 8.1 native maps API is using Bing Maps API or HERE maps API now?
2. Are HERE apps such as HERE maps, drive+, and transit stop support on Windows platform now? As they are not available anymore in the app store.

Appreciate any reply, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In reference to your transit question, you can use the Bing REST api to query routes specific for Transit.

An example can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg636958.aspx

In short you do your requests through a specific URL : `http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/V1/Routes/Transit?...`

In regards to the HERE apps, well currently not sure what is going to happen with them. But the Maps app from Microsoft is slowly getting most of the features that where in those HERE apps, so I guess they are migrating stuff.

Comment: I could not use REST api as I need the map to work offline, any workaround for this?

Comment: Hmm sorry, not aware of how to do this offline